# Legacy database Django

Tags: python, django

I followed the steps for linking to a legacy app in Django. Everything seems to have migrated fine, but when I try to access the data, I get No module named xxx.models
Here is settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'spam_filter.db'),
}
```

}

I also added spamfilter under installed apps.

Here is an example of my model class:

```
class Inbound(models.Model):
    field_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='_id', primary_key=True, blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    filter_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    day = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    rate_controlled = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    bad_recipient = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    spam = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    virus = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    quarantined = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    tagged = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    allowed = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    total_received = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

When I enter from spamfilter.models import Inbound, I get the error that spamfilter.models is not found.

What am I doing wrong.

```
Directory Structure
C:.
│   dir.txt
│   pip-selfcheck.json
│   spamfilter proj.wpr
│   spamfilter proj.wpu
│   spam_filter.db
│   tree.log
│   tree.txt
│   
├───Include
│       
├───Lib
│   │           
│   ├───distutils
│   │           
│   ├───encodings
│   │           
│   ├───importlib
│   ├───site-packages
├───Scripts
│           
├───spamfilter
│   │   manage.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   spam_filter.db
│   │   
│   └───spamfilter
│       │   settings.py
│       │   urls.py
│       │   wsgi.py
│       │   __init__.py
│               
└───tcl
    └───tk8.6
        ├───demos
```

Comment: did you do the migrations ? `python manage.py makemigrations` ?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the folder structure for your project.

Comment: I did complete the migrations with no problems.

Comment: I updated my original post with the directory structure.